# int(intput()) inside a function does not work?

Tags: python, function, input

when I try to use the following function:

```
def ea():
    x,y = int(input("enter age:")),input("enter name:")
    if x > 0:
        print(f"My name is {y} and I am {365*(x)} on earth")
    else:
        ea()
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: int() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.
```

I don't understand why as `int(input())` works when not used in a function. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you defined ```int``` as a function somewhere else? Because ```int``` needs an argument to convert to an integer

Comment: As provided, the code works fine.

Comment: Ah! Yes I made a typo in a function before and that is why I overwrote the original function. Do you know how I can reverse that?

Comment: I got it thanks everyone!! I will close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ea():
    x, y = input("enter your name and age: ").split(" ")
    y = int(y)
    if y > 0:
        print(f"My name is {x} and I am {365*(y)} on earth")
    else:
        ea()
```

Output :

```
>>> ea()
enter your name and age: thor 18
My name is thor and I am 6570 on earth
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This

```
def ea():
    x = int(input("enter age:"))
    y = input("enter name:")
    if x > 0:
        print(f"My name is {y} and I am {365*(x)} on earth")
    else:
        ea()
```